# How do I prove: if f(a) = f(b) = 0, then there is a greatest lower bound c and least upper bound d such that f(c) = f(d) = 0

Tags: calculus

I'm having trouble proving this one question from Calculus, 4th Edition, by Spivak. The full problem is:

Suppose that f is continuous on [a, b] and that f(a) = f(b) = 0. Suppose also that f(x₀) > 0 for some x₀ in [a, b]. Prove that there are numbers c and d with a ≤ c < x₀ < d ≤ b such that f(c) = f(d) = 0, but f(x) > 0 for all x in (c, d).

My proof outline is this: There is a set A such that A = {x: f(x) = 0}. I need to prove, for set A, that c is the greatest lower bound, and d is the least upper bound. To do this, I want to show that f(c) = f(d) = 0. However, I'm not sure if I'm headed in the right direction; I don't think it's rigorous enough, and I don't know if my approach even makes sense.

Any advice on how to at least get started is appreciated.

Comment: If $f(x_0)>0$, there is a neighborhood I=[$x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon$] , such  that $f(x_0)>0$ for all $x\in I$

Comment: Why not take $c:=\sup\{x\in[a,x_0):f(x)=0\}$?

Comment: Thanks for the advice everyone. John Dawkins, I used your idea, and I changed it a little so that my proof is more like this:

A = { x∈[a, x₀]: f(x)  = 0}. The least upper bound property states that, "if A is a set of real numbers, A is not empty, and A is bounded above, then A has a least upper bound." In this case, A is bounded above by x₀, therefore A has a least upper bound, namely c. I will use similar reasoning to show that d is also the least upper bound of [x₀, b].

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is continuous, $f(a) = f(b) = 0$, and $f(x_0) > 0$, it must be that there exists some interval $(x_0 - \alpha, x_0 + \alpha)$ such that for all $\beta \in (x_0 - \alpha, x_0 + \alpha), f(\beta) > 0$.

(You can prove that this is true if you feel the need: consider the intervals $(x_0 - \alpha, x_0)$ and $(x_0, x_0+\alpha)$: for every point in each interval, apply the intermediate value theorem.)

Anyway, then you can let $c$ be the point right before the interval $(x_0-\alpha, x_0+\alpha)$, and $d$ the point directly after. Constructing something like $c = \inf \{\alpha | f(x_0 - \alpha) \neq 0\}$ should work, and $d = \sup \{\alpha | f(x_0 + \alpha) \neq 0\}$.